# What is the sum of the binomial coefficients ${n\choose p}$ over prime numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

What is known about the asymptotics, lower and upper bound of the sum of the binomial coefficients

$$
S_n = {n\choose 2} + {n\choose 3} + {n\choose 5} + \cdots + {n\choose p}
$$

where the sum runs over all primes $\le n$?

**My approach:** I am working on a solution more of brute force in nature using Stirling's inequality

$$
\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-n + \frac{1}{12n+1}} < n! < \sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-n + \frac{1}{12n}}
$$

and [Axler's upper and lower bounds on the $n$-th prime](https://docserv.uni-duesseldorf.de/servlets/DerivateServlet/Derivate-28284/pdfa-1b.pdf).

**Note:** I had [posted this question in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930593/what-is-the-sum-of-the-binomial-coefficients-n-choose-p-over-prime-numbers) and got a good answer with a lower bound which depends on a conjecture and an unconditional upper bound? I am reposting this question in MO with the hope to getting an unconditional lower bound as well as sharper upper and lower bounds.

Comment: The answer is we don't know.  The question amounts to understanding primes in intervals like $[x, x+\sqrt{x}]$ which is wide open.

Comment: The numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A121497 but nothing there about asymptotics.